# How to delete a line if the letter after nth space matches a criteria?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I have a large text file with the data looking something like below:

```
ATOM 3515 CA GLY C 43 1.094 36.439 24.619 1.00 44.14 C
```

How would I delete a line, depending on whether the Character after the 4th space is a 'C'? I've seen a way to do it with `cut` like

```
cut -f1,4 -d' '
```

That removes everything from beyond the match.

Is there a way to do that for the whole line? I can see a few ways to do it in other ways, but I'd like to do it specifically off the 4th space, that way I can be definite (or more so) it's not going to parse out the wrong bits somewhere in the depths of the file.

Comment: you can also use grep... `grep -vE '^([^ ]+ ){4}C' file` though awk is best suited with easy column processing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would I delete a line, depending on whether the Character after the 4th space is a `'C'`

You can use awk for this:

```
awk '$5 !~ /^C/' file
```

- `$5` is field # 5, i.e. field after 4th space
- `/^C/` is a check to assert that 5th field starts with `C`

You can get same output using `substr` function as well:

```
awk 'substr($5, 1, 1) != "C"' file
```

Comment: It's official. I'm a fool. Was swimming around in that area, I don't know why I didn't see it. Thanks.